# Specify column type in pycassa

Tags: python, cassandra, pycassa

I want to do the equivalence of these CLI command in pycassa:

```
CREATE COLUMN FAMILY users
WITH comparator = UTF8Type
AND key_validation_class=UTF8Type
AND column_metadata = [
{column_name: full_name, validation_class: UTF8Type}
{column_name: email, validation_class: UTF8Type}
{column_name: state, validation_class: UTF8Type}
{column_name: gender, validation_class: UTF8Type}
{column_name: birth_year, validation_class: LongType}
];
```

What is the equivalence in pycassa?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. Don't know much about python client, still ...

```
 validators = {'full_name': UTF8_TYPE,
              'email': UTF8_TYPE,
              'state': UTF8_TYPE,
              'gender': UTF8_TYPE,
              'birth_year': LONG_TYPE}
 sys.create_column_family('TestKeyspace', 'TestCF', super=False,
              comparator_type=UTF8Type,
              key_validation_class=UTF8Type, 
              column_validation_classes=validators)
```

Comment: This is not in my original question, but how do you define the composite dynamic column, like ("name", 1234) as key?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your other question:
    key_validation_class='CompositeType(UTF8Type, UTF8Type)'